# Laravel Mix Incorrect Url for Bootstrap Fonts

Tags: webpack, laravel-5.5, laravel-mix

I'm using laravel 5.5 and I'm trying to compile a less file with some bootstrap overrides.

I have the following in my webpack.mix.js file:

```
 mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .less('resources/assets/less/app.less', 'public/css').options({
         processCssUrls: false
    });
```

app.less is as follows:

```
@import "~bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
@import "_variables.less";

// custom styles
```

_variables.less is as follows:

```
// Brands
@brand-primary:      #005689;

// Iconography
@icon-font-path:        "../fonts/";
```

however the compiled app.css is generating the font-face url as follows:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
   src: url('../../../node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');

}
```

Looks like its generating the url relative to the import `@import "~bootstrap/less/bootstrap"`

How can I force it to generate the font-face url as:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
   src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Fixed by doing the following:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .less('resources/assets/less/app.less', 'public/css', { relativeUrls: false
    })
  .options({
     processCssUrls: false
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed helped me a lot.

Comment: Working perfect, Thanks !